# Regex For Parsing a Definition In Plain English with Example

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a small parser for a definition of a word with an example of usage in plain English.

**For Example**

- **Example 1** - "Foo: The companion of bar e.g. I have class called FooBar"
- **Example 2** - "Foo: The companion of bar for example I have class called FooBar"

I want both of the above example to be decomposed to:

`[('Foo', 'The companion of bar', 'I have class called FooBar')]`

This is the code I have so far

```
import re
EXAMPLE_REGEX = re.compile("(.*):(.*)(e.?g.?|(for )?example)(.*)")
print EXAMPLE_REGEX.findall('Foo: The companion of bar e.g. I have class called FooBar')
```

**Output:** `[('Foo', ' The companion of bar ', 'e.g.', '', ' I have class called FooBar')]`

How can I avoid the extra `'e.g.'` and `''` in the output?

Comment: Use `(?:)` to ignore the capture group: `(?:e.?g.?|(?:for )?example)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more elegant solution out there, but you can convert your optional elements to non capturing groups (`?:`):

```
import re
EXAMPLE_REGEX = re.compile("(.*):(.*)(?:e.?g.?|(?:for )?example)(.*)")
print EXAMPLE_REGEX.findall('Foo: The companion of bar e.g. I have class called FooBar')
```

the key being `(?:e.?g.?|(?:for )`

Comment: This works! Thanks. What do you think a more elegant solution would look like?